# If $X\in L^p$ and $Y\in L^q$ with $p,q>1$ is it true that $XY$ integrable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X,Y$ r.v's on a probability space, such that $E|X|^p<\infty$ and $E|Y|^q<\infty$, for $p,q>1$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Is it true that $E|XY|<\infty$?

My question comes from this: I have to prove the conditional Holder's inequality under these assumptions. And I was wondering whether the LHS of it, namely $E[|XY|\, \, | \mathcal{G}]$ is at all defined and I couldn't come up with a proof that $XY$ is indeed integrable.

Comment: This follows from the ordinary Hölder inequality.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I know how to prove the conditional version of Holder. My question was something different.

Comment: Sorry, but please read what I have written. The fact that $XY\in L^1$ follows from $X\in L^p$ and $Y\in L^q$ is a direct consequence of the usual Hölder inequality.

Comment: @perlman: So, what you're asking essentially is whether $XY$ is integrable with respect to the measure that comes from the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I am sorry I didn't get your answer in the first place. It is indeed straightforward. Thank you a lot

Comment: @stressed-out No, I wanted just that $XY$ is integrable in our initial $\sigma-$algebra, which comes from the Holder inequality immediately. I had to prove the conditional Holder and for some reason I was confused and I didn't take for granted the unconditional version in this part. Sorry for my silly question guys.